# Laravel 5.5 - a particular field is not inserting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a laravel project which is in laravel 5.5. I have manually created an extra field "uploaded_image" in the existing "product" table. When I passed the data into the laravel controller (ProductController.php), all the existing fields are updated except the newly created field. Below is my ProductController code:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'product_name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'rating' => 'required'
    ]);

    $uploaded_image = $request->input('uploaded_image');
    $data['uploaded_image'] = $uploaded_image['filename']; // which is abc.png
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    $product->update($data);

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `uploaded_image` in `Product` model `fillable` array

```
protected $fillable = [
     'uploaded_image'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to by sending the file name as string

```
$uploaded_image = $request->input('uploaded_image');
$data['uploaded_image'] = $uploaded_image; // which is abc.png
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
$product->update($data);

return response()->json($data);
```

or if you want the file itself sending

```
$uploaded_image = $request->file('uploaded_image');
$data['uploaded_image'] = $uploaded_image->getFilename(); // which is abc.png
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
$product->update($data);

return response()->json($data);
```